# How to construct 32-bit uint in Python using ctypes bit field?

Tags: python, endianness, bit-fields

I would like to construct an unsigned 32-bit int using Python3 ctypes bit field, as follows:

```
c_uint = ctypes.c_uint32

class Flags_bits(ctypes.LittleEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [ 
            ("a", c_uint, 4),
            ("b", c_uint, 4),
            ("c", c_uint, 4),
            ("d", c_uint, 4),
            ("e", c_uint, 4),
            ("f", c_uint, 4),
            ("g", c_uint, 4),
            ("h", c_uint, 4)]
```

When I substitute `Flags_bits` with specific integer values,

```
aa = Flags_bits(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
print(hexlify(aa).decode('utf-8'))
```

The output is

```
21436587
```

I was expecting an output like

```
87654321 # binary of 1000 0111 0110 0101 0100 0011 0010 0001
```

Since Little-endian constructs bits starting with the low bit. How can I obtain the expected output? Is there anything I did wrong? Could someone be so kind to help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It IS stored little-endian.  The `binascii.hexlify` function reads the value as a set of bytes, and returns a string of those bytes.  It's not treating them as an integer.  As bytes, the values are 21 43 65 87.  Unless you treat a set of bytes as a multi-byte unit, endianness does not apply.

If you want to see the value as a 32-bit integer, do this, which results in 87654321:

```
import struct
...
aa = Flags_bits(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
aa_int = struct.unpack('I',aa)[0]
print(hex(aa_int))
```

Bitfield structures are problematic, even in C.  Honestly, in many cases it's way easier to shift and mask:

```
def Flags_bits(*data):
    val = 0
    for n in reversed(data):
        val = (val << 4) | n
    return val
```